# Snowflake SSRS ODBC error : No active warehouse selected in the current session. Select an active warehouse with the 'use warehouse' command

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using SSRS (SQL Server reporting services) to display reports, my datasource is Snowflake

I have installed the ODBC snowflake driver and configured it properly
[Click here to view the ODBC configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEuhb.png)

I have created a shared datasource on the SSRS server (via Report manager) and put in my own credentials and the connection works fine
[Click here to view the connection on the SSRS Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suRyZ.png)

I'm able to build the SSRS report without any issues, when I run the report, everything works fine, I can publish the report on the server and the report renders perfectly fine on the browser

The issue is when i go back to the report the **next day**, i'm presented with an error:

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
>   Query execution failed for dataset
>   '***insert_name_of_my_dataset_here***'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
>
> ERROR [57P03] No active warehouse selected in the current session.
>   Select an active warehouse with the 'use warehouse' command.

So, this also means that the following doesn't work neither:

- Subscriptions
- Cache refresh
- Snapshots

The only thing that works is if I open my report in SSRS Report builder, I right-click **EACH** of my datasets ("each" is very important, it doesn't work if i don't do all of them), I run the queries manually for each of them, and then the "connection" or "session" is "re-activated" and the report runs fine, both locally **AND** on the server...note i do not have to re-publish the report on the server for it to run

[Click here to view screenshots of my process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y20iN.png)

Steps I have taken to addresss the issue (that didn't yield any resolution):

- I have tried putting the **"use warehouse WAREHOUSE_NAME;" command** before each dataset's SQL script, but Snowflake's API doesn't allow multiple SQL commands to be sent, so I already saw that this functionality was in the development pipeline for Snowflake and found this link: https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net/issues/33 - this work was started in 2018 and the last update dates from Apr 2019 that says they are starting to address the JDBC driver...no mention for the ODBC driver yet
- I have set the snowflake parameter **client-session-keep-alive** to true (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#client-session-keep-alive), but according to the community portal: A similar "keep alive" parameter is not currently available for the ODBC driver. Instead, you could issue a dummy query every few hours to keep the connection alive. (https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/faq-how-long-can-my-jdbcodbc-connection-remain-idle)
- List item
- I have tried to create a cache refresh plan or a snapshot schedule that creates a snapshot or caches the report every 3 hours, and it works for the first schedule, but fails with the error for the other ones
- The only thing I didn't try is to have snowflake never close the connection and keep the warehouse in the "started" state indefinitely...but this would increase my cost, and i'm pretty sure it won't work since the session would end anyways after 4 hours...

Any assistance is welcome!

Thanks

Specs:

- SSRS 2014
- Snowflake X-small
- ODBC-64 bit driver, installed from the
  snowflake driver repository (tested with 32-bit also, but 64-bit is
  the one that is visible to SSRS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be related with the data warehouse name (in the ODBC settings)? Is there a typo? COSNUMER_WH or CONSUMER_WH?

Comment: OMG really, lol!! Let me fix this!! i'll get back to you after 4 hours and see if this was the issue, i'm shocked i didn't see this! LOL

Comment: Wow, i'm ashamed, it took me 30mins to write this text, and all it was is a typo!! SMH! Thank you so much for pointing this out, everything works magnificently now! :D

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same kind of issue and fixed adding the corresponding role with the data warehouse.

In the data warehouse add role with USAGE.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend setting default "context" configurations for situations like this, setting default role, warehouse, database, and schema with commands such as this:

ALTER USER xyz SET DEFAULT_WAREHOUSE = 'WH_NAME_HERE' ;

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-user.html

Comment: Hi, we tried so many things i forgot to say we had already set the default_warehouse for the user that will be running the reports, thanks for pointing this out though!

Comment: the next thing I'd do is check the user's query history, to see what role/warehouse/db/schema the session had when the query ran, for some reason the "context" of the user's session seems incorrect, which is why I normally set all four of these configurations for these "batch" (programatic / system account) type of users.

Comment: I tried to check the logs, but since there was a typo, my theory is that the command didn't even reach snowflake because it couldn't find the warehouse in the snowflake environment, thanks for all your input

How silly to think this was just a typo thing, but i'm happy to have it running now!